# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str when using len(), input() and print()

Tags: python

since this next simple code worked for me:

```
print(len(input("¿whats your name? i will give you how many letters it has if you tell me: ")))
```

I tried to make it fancier by trying to code a more "complete" answer:

```
print("your name has " + len(input("whats your name? i will give tell you how many letters it has if you tell me: ")) + " in it")
```

but it doesnt seem to work out.

the "output" tell me this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 7, in 
print("your name has " + len(input("whats your name? i will give tell you how many letters it has if you tell me: ")) + " in it")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str


Comment: For future reference, try searching your error on google before posting a question. While you are first learning to code, 99% of the questions and errors you will have, have already been answered on this site. As far as the error, you are getting this error because you are adding a string and an integer which aren't compatible for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can not concatenate an integer (which is what len returns) with the strings before and after it, but you can put it between curly brackets in a f' string like this:

```
print(f'your name has {len(input("What is your name? I will give tell you how many letters it has if you tell me: "))} letters in it.')
```

Answer (score 0):

`len()` returns integer and you need a string to concatenate.

try converting len to string using `str()` like this:

```
print("your name has " + str(len(input("whats your name? i will give tell you how many letters it has if you tell me: "))) + " in it")
```